# Sheets Data Validation In Colum "O" is updated when Colum "P" values are +7

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu, return-value

I have in Colum "O", on a dropdown list of two values (Yes, No).
I got a scrip running that every time I tick it to "Yes", in Colum "P" I get a timestamp of todays date.
Now, what I'm looking for is, after 7 days of this timestamp, the Value in the dropdown list in Colum "O" goes back to "No", and while doing so, it clears out the timestamp in Colum "P".
This way I could restart the process, of clicking "Yes", get a new timestamp, and after 7 days, it resets itself.

I've been digging deep, but cant find anything helpful.

Regards!

Comment: Please provide you current code

Comment: function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Inventory" ) { //checks that we're on Sheet1 or not
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 14 ) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column A
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //checks if the adjacent cell is empty or not?
nextCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
}

Comment: Please post it into your question

Comment: You are going to have to use a time based trigger to change the values with out human intervention.

Comment: Cant i just make a new column (=>7) where   ="date"+7, and run a script that turns the value in the dropdown list to "No ", when Date column and new Column (=>7) match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('Entry');
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var s = e.range.getSheet();
  if (s.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 14) {
    e.source.toast('Flag1');
    let dt = new Date();
    if (e.range.offset(0, 1).getValue() === '') {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(dt);
    }
    let thv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate() - 7).valueOf();
    s.getRange(1, 15, s.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().forEach((el, i) => {
      if (new Date(el).valueOf() <= thv) {
        s.getRange(i + 1,14,1,2).setValues([["No",""]]);
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, im sorry for my ignorance, first time dealing with scripting, but this is happening on my sheet2, and i can only run the scrip if im on sheet1, how can i make it so that the activesheet is the 2nd?

im assuming thats why im getting this error  TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEdit @ Inventory Reset.gs:3

Comment: First of all you cannot run this sort of function from the script editor without supplying the event object which is normally supplied by the onEdit trigger.  Keep in mind there is a simple trigger that is created on any edit of any sheet in a spreadsheet and if you have a function named onEdit then the trigger with run that function an populate the first parameter of that function with the event object.  However, when it is run from the script editor the event object is not available.

Comment: I'm not understanding why you speak of sheet2 and sheet1 when your original code contains the following `s.getName() == "Inventory"`

Comment: I was just trying to figure out why the error is poping up, but i think i understood your explanations.

However, i tried to test it out, with day+1, and left one tab on "Yes" so that a timestamp was created, but nothing changed today, and even though i have an event subject, i keep getting the same error, cant define range.

Im sorry, maybe im missing something really basic, but im a newb on this, but still isnt working out for me

Comment: if day is a Date() object then day + 1 means nothing but in a Date constructor like new Date(2022,0,1 + 7).valueOf() it changes the number of milliseconds by 168 hours

Comment: I ment i just did this small change ,to test it out in a space of 24 hours 

 let thv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate() - 1).valueOf()

Comment: Try it now.  Might need to change the sheet name